# Getting error while Install android studio on linux system?

Tags: linux, android-studio, installation

Once i install android-studio on my linux, and somehow, i uninstalled this.
After that i tried to install, but unfortunatilly i can't install this.
I am fresher on linux system, I can't understand any error.
Can You please help?

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1693, in request
    (response, new_content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1155, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
```

Comment: which distribution are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

try installing it through snap

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install android-studio
```

if you are facing the error

**error: This revision of snap “android-studio” was published using classic confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at risk.**

try installing

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

Comment: $ sudo snap install android-studio


error: cannot install "android-studio": Post
       "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": x509: certificate signed by
       unknown authority

Comment: $ sudo apt install android-studio-classic

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package android-studio-classic

Comment: Tried this way. also getting error.

Comment: for certificate try: sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
for classic, there is a space and - missing in your command

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20211016).
ca-certificates set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
=====================
$ sudo snap install android-studio --classic
error: cannot install "android-studio": Post
       "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": x509: certificate signed by
       unknown authority

Comment: latest certificate is already used.

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing again. Maybe there are some files left.